# Сортировка в MySQL

Tags: сортировка, mysql

Есть запрос:

```
   SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `full_url`, `text`, `type_causes`, `time`
    FROM `url_blacklist`
   WHERE `del` = '0'
   ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Как сделать, чтобы записи с `type = 0` были выше остальных, но при этом сортировка `ORDER BY id DESC` сохранилась?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `full_url`, `text`, `type_causes`, `time`
    FROM `url_blacklist`
   WHERE `del` = '0'
   ORDER BY `type_causes` ASC, `id` DESC
```

Comment: @Get, благодарю.